# Receiving data from GPS

Tags: gps

I would like to build a standalone device (not connected to wired internet) that contains a GPS chip that will send the device location to a server.

My questions are:

1. The device should be able to connect to the server from a distance, that means I need a good coverage. Would you recommend using GSM technology? If that's the case, can I have a few hints to where do I start? do I need to connect my GPS to communication modules? do I have to use a SIM card?
2. How do I send the data to my server? (according to the tech you think is best in question #1)?

Comment: Why not buy one of these off-the-shelf?  They make them for $50 or so.

Comment: it's a hands on project, I can't use off-shelf products... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question. "from a distance"? 1 meter? 10 meters? 1 km? 1000km? A million kilometers?

If the device will be too far away for Bluetooth and WiFi, you would like to use GPRS/EDGE or similar (that's mobile phone technology), and in that case you need a SIM card.

But suppose your device will be roaming Greenland or Antarctica or other places on the Earth without mobile phone coverage, Satellite Phone is the only solution. That would be pretty expensive. The device could even be a space probe like Voyager 1, and you would need big antennas and probably several ground stations. Although a space probe would not benefit much from GPS

Question 2 is equally hard to answer.

However, if you are doing a hobby project and do not plan to spend too much money, I would suggest an Arduino based system. Arduino can communicate with Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth, GPRS. It'll probably not communicate with SatPhones, but "speaks" RS232 (TTL level), One-Wire, I2C, etc.